# Why does std::upper_bound() have linear complexity?

Tags: c++, performance, time-complexity, binary-search, upperbound

I was reading the guide on USACO Silver talking about sorted sets, and I came across [this warning](https://usaco.guide/silver/intro-sorted-sets#sorted-sets) (`s` is a `std::set` of integers):

> **Warning**!
> Suppose that we replace `s.upper_bound(7)` with `upper_bound(begin(s),end(s),7)`, which was the syntax that we used for vectors in the prerequisite module. This will still output the expected results, but its time complexity is **linear** in the size of the set `s` rather than logarithmic, so make sure to avoid it!

What do they mean ?

```cpp
   upper_bound(s.begin(), s.end(), 7 ); // O(n) ?
   s.upper_bound(7);                    // O(log N) ?
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's because a `std::set` doesn't support random access iterators. In order to get from `a` to `a + 200` the algorithm would have to increase `a` 200 times.

For this reason, the `std::set` has member functions for finding the [`upper_bound`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/upper_bound) and [`lower_bound`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) efficiently.

Comment: so lower_bound(v.begin(), v.end(), 7); (where v is a vector) is o(logN) right ?

Comment: @AbdullahKassar in best case yeah. O(N) is always worst case. But a container with non-random memory access make it even costier, so implementation which have access to the inner working of container is preferable for these (which is actually noted on cppreference and I believe there was such note in standard). Imagine trying to find upper bound in a linked list?

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie Why only best case? And how much costier than O(N) for a container with non-random memory access?

Comment: @KellyBundy By cost of accessing random i-th element of container N times, which wouldn't be constant. Encapsulated implementations for map\multimap\set may take advantage of sorted nature and being able to reach for the random-access representation of structure. Big problem if we do not want to look through entire container.

Comment: @AbdullahKassar No, not o(logN) but O(logN).

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie That doesn't really answer the questions. I think you're wrong about both, `lower_bound` on a vector is O(logN) worst case as well, and on a container with non-random memory access (but O(1) for iterator increment) it's still not costier than O(N). And it shouldn't be *"accessing random i-th element of container N times"*. But you have way more C++ rep than me, so maybe I'm overlooking something...

Answer (score 2):

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/upper_bound):

> for non-LegacyRandomAccessIterators, the number of iterator increments is linear. Notably, std::map, std::multimap, std::set, and std::multiset iterators are not random access